# Porque Java me bloquea ejecutar mi aplicacion

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

He empaquetado una aplicacion hecha en JavaFX con librerias etc usando Launch4j y InnoSetup Compiler.
La cuestion es que en mi pc funcniono perfectamente la app instalandola a la hora de hacer la prueba en otra pc me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

le recomendaria que revise la configuración de java, podria intentar entrar al panel de control de java, en el apartado de seguridad hay debe aparecerle la opcion de "lista de sitios" y agregar el **path completo** de su aplicación y guardar los cambios y intentar ejecutarla de nuevo.

Comment: Es lo que hice la cuestión es que tengo la misma configuración de seguridad de java que la otra pc y en aquella no se ejecuta